# How to make colours in level plot in lattice change smoothly?

Tags: r

I've made a level graph in lattice that shows changes in temperature in lake water column with water depth and month. The colours, however don't change smoothly. Instead the graph is divided into different colour squares.

Here's the code I used:

```
levelplot(Temperature ~ Date*Depth, data = lakedata,
xlab = "Month", ylab = "Depth (m)",
ylim=c(11,0),
col.regions=terrain.colors(100))
```

I've also tried contour plot in `lattice`, but despite graduate change of contours, the colours stays in squares:

```
contourplot(Temperature ~ Date*Depth, data = lakedata,
xlab = "Month", ylab = "Depth (m)",
ylim=c(11,0),
region=TRUE,
aspect = "fill",
col.regions = terrain.colors(100))
```

I guess the problem might be caused by the fact that explanatory variables are categorical. Is there anything that can be done to smooth the change in colours?

Comment: Use the `cuts` argument. Show how you load the data and I'll show you how.

Comment: You will only get squares with `levelplot`. The size of the squares will depend on the vertical and horizontal resolutions.

Comment: Hi,   I use: lakedata<- read.table(file = "Water_parameters_depth_profile.txt",
                  header = TRUE,
                  dec = "."). Thanks! Justyna